# how many unique powers are for x^y for x in 1-1000 and y in 1-1000 using R

Tags: r

Using R, calculate for x and y be integers ∈ [1, 1000], How many unique powers, x^y exist. 
This is what I have right now, just don't know how to eliminate the duplicate numbers,

```
x<-1:1000
y<-1:1000
for (i in x)
{
    for (j in y){
       print(i^j)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would solve the problem for x and y over 1:10 each, and then try to generalize the solution. Also look into factoring the x and y's....2^2 = 4^1, 2^3 = 8^1, 2^4 = 16^1..... and on and on. Actually that is probably the only way to solve this problem. 1000^1000 is not a number that any computer can calculate.

Comment: You should be asking yourself why your professor is asking you to do impossible tasks.

Comment: @Jotorious, actually not true: in Python3 `1000**1000` works perfectly fine (Python3 transparently transitions to arbitrary-precision integers when necessary).  But I agree that factoring is the smart way to do it.

Comment: @BondedDust true, there is no reason to give such a task.

Comment: Does 1000^1000 = 1 with 3000 zeros behind it?

Comment: This is not an intractable problem, and it's a counting problem that does not require calculating all the powers (indeed 1000^1000 > `.Machine$integer.max`).  Here's a hint: (a) there is 1 power of 1 and (b) for integers greater than 1, if there is no integer root of that number then there are 1000 unique powers of that number, otherwise if n is a power of smaller integer, then you can calculate the number of integers powers of n (e.g. there are 500 unique integer powers of 4 that aren't in 2^1:1000).

Comment: @BondedDust  One reason for such an assignment is to do combinatorics in a language that can't actually handle the numbers you are counting.

Comment: @Jthorpe, so 1000 unique powers for every number that is either a prime or not a power of a prime, and for numbers that are powers of prime, divide 1000 by the power of the prime. So for 4 there are 1000/2 =500 (because 4 = 2^2) and for 8 are 1000/3 (because (8 = 2^3) and for 9 there are 500 (because 9 = 3^2)?

So the intersection of 6^(1:1000) and 10^(1:0000)  or 12^(1:1000)  is null? Out of curiosity, how is this known or a given? Is there some theorem which dictates this?

Comment: It's just side effect of the fact that if `b = a^n`,  you can re-write `b^m` as `(a^n)^m` which is the same as `a^(n*m)`.   Hence, for example, `8^100` which  can be written as `2^300` is in `2^1:100` because `300 < 1000`

Answer (score 15):

A combinatorial approach to this could split the numbers from 1-1000 into equivalence classes where each number in the class is the power of some other number. For instance, we would split the numbers 1-10 into (1), (2, 4, 8), (3, 9), (5), (6), (7), (10). None of the powers of values between equivalence classes will coincide, so we can just handle each equivalence class separately.

```
num.unique.comb <- function(limit) {
  # Count number of powers in each equivalence class (labeled by lowest val)
  num.powers <- rep(0, limit)

  # Handle 1 as special case
  num.powers[1] <- 1

  # Beyond sqrt(limit), all unhandled numbers are in own equivalence class
  handled <- c(T, rep(F, limit-1))
  for (base in 2:ceiling(sqrt(limit))) {
    if (!handled[base]) {
      # Handle all the values in 1:limit that are powers of base
      num.handle <- floor(log(limit, base))
      handled[base^(1:num.handle)] <- T

      # Compute the powers of base that we cover
      num.powers[base] <- length(unique(as.vector(outer(1:num.handle, 1:limit))))
    }
  }
  num.powers[!handled] <- limit

  # Handle sums too big for standard numeric types
  library(gmp)
  print(sum(as.bigz(num.powers)))
}
num.unique.comb(10)
# [1] 76
num.unique.comb(1000)
# [1] 978318
```

One nice property of this combinatorial approach is that it's very fast compared to a brute-force approach. For instance, it takes less than 0.1 seconds to compute with limit set to 1000. This allows us to compute the result for much larger values:

```
# ~0.15 seconds
num.unique.comb(10000)
# [1] 99357483

# ~4 seconds
num.unique.comb(100000)
# [1] 9981335940

# ~220 seconds
num.unique.comb(1000000)
# [1] 999439867182
```

This is a pretty neat result -- in under 4 minutes we can compute the number of unique values within 1 trillion numbers, where each number can have up to 6 million digits!

**Update**: Based on this combinatorial code I've updated the [OEIS entry for this sequence](https://oeis.org/A126254) to include terms up to 10,000.

Answer (score 7):

A brute-force approach would be to just compute all the powers and count the number of unique values:

```
num.unique.bf <- function(limit) {
  length(unique(as.vector(sapply(1:limit, function(x) x^(1:limit)))))
}
num.unique.bf(10)
# [1] 76
```

A problem with this brute-force analysis is that you are dealing with large numbers that will create numerical issues. For instance:

```
1000^1000
# [1] Inf
```

As a result we get an inaccurate value:

```
# Wrong due to numerical issues!
num.unique.bf(1000)
# [1] 119117
```

However, a package like the `gmp` can enable us to compute even numbers as large as 1000^1000. My computer has trouble storing all 1 million numbers in memory at once, so I'll write them to a file (size for n=1000 is 1.2 GB on my computer) and then compute the number of unique values in that file:

```
library(gmp)
num.unique.bf2 <- function(limit) {
  sink("foo.txt")
  for (x in 1:limit) {
    vals <- as.bigz(x)^(1:limit)
    for (idx in 1:limit) {
      cat(paste0(as.character(vals[idx]), "\n"))
    }
  }
  sink()
  as.numeric(system("sort foo.txt | uniq | wc -l", intern=T))
}
num.unique.bf2(10)
# [1] 76
num.unique.bf2(1000)
# [1] 978318
```

A quick visit to the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A126254) (click the link for the first 1000 values) shows that this is correct. This approach is rather slow (roughly 40 minutes on my computer), and combinatorial approaches should be significantly faster.

Comment: although it might take more than 40 minutes to work out the combinatorics from scratch ...

Comment: @BenBolker true, but the combinatorial approach enables runs at limits (e.g. 100,000) that would have been impossible with this brute force approach.

Comment: I was just snarking; the combinatorial approach is absolutely better.  But if *all* you needed to do was solve the original problem (or, say, a smaller version of the problem that wouldn't require arbitrary-precision integers), brute force might be the best option.